# Swift:Unable to center ImageView on ScrollView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am attempting to display an `imageView` at the center in the X and Y axis onto a `scrollView`, fitted nicely within the width of the device when I run the app. I would also want to pan and zoom the `imageView`. I have tried almost all the solution that has been posted on SO and also followed this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/560-uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started) but somehow it just doesn't resolve my issue. The image is generated from a PDF.

I do my layout programmatically. My implementation so far:

```
let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let sv = UIScrollView()
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    return sv
}()

let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return iv
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),

        ])

    imageView.image = obtainThumbnail()
}

fileprivate func updateMinZoomScaleForSize(_ size: CGSize) {
    let widthScale = size.width / imageView.bounds.width
    let heightScale = size.height / imageView.bounds.height
    let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    scrollView.zoomScale = minScale
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.bounds.size)
}

func obtainThumbnail() -> UIImage? {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "drawings", withExtension: "pdf") else {return nil}

    guard
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
        let page = PDFDocument(data: data)?.page(at: 0) else {
            return nil
    }

    let pageSize = page.bounds(for: .mediaBox)
    return page.thumbnail(of: CGSize(width: pageSize.width, height: pageSize.height), for: .mediaBox)
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}
```

This is my desired results when I run the app.
[image]

And this is the results when I run the app now, overstretched.
[image]

Would anyone advice what am I missing?

Comment: Try changing `contentMode = .scaleAspectFill` to `scaleAspectFit`

Comment: @Magnas Tried, same result as above

Comment: When you calculate `minScale` in `updateMinZoomScaleForSize` the frames of both `scrollView` and `imageView` are zero.

Comment: @Magnas if thats the case, where should I calculate?

Answer (score 0):

I think that views are loaded lazily in `UIViewController`s so making the calculation later in the UI lifecycle should solve the problem. Removing the call in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and instead using:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.bounds.size)
}
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work well, there are two places to fix:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),

       //First place.
       // scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
       // scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        scrollView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),



        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),


        ])

    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    imageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "temp2.png")
     //second place.
    imageView.sizeToFit()
```

Hope it solved your problem well.

If you need the view in the middle, may try the following method:

```
let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let sv = UIScrollView()
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.backgroundColor = .lightGray
  sv.contentMode = .center

 return sv
}()

 let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return iv
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)



    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([


     scrollView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor ),

    scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor ),


        scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
   scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor),


        ])

    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    imageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "temp2.png")
    imageView.sizeToFit()
    updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.bounds.size)


}


var constantHeight : CGFloat{

    return  min(view.bounds.height, imageView.bounds.height *  scrollView.zoomScale)
}
var constantWidth : CGFloat{
    return min( view.bounds.width, imageView.bounds.width *  scrollView.zoomScale)
}

    lazy var constraintHeight: NSLayoutConstraint = {

     return      scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constantHeight)

}()

    lazy  var constraintWeight: NSLayoutConstraint = {
    return
        scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: constantWidth)

}()



fileprivate func updateMinZoomScaleForSize(_ size: CGSize) {

    let widthScale = size.width / imageView.bounds.width
    let heightScale = size.height / imageView.bounds.height
    let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)

    imageView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: minScale * imageView.bounds.width, height: minScale*imageView.bounds.height)


    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
    scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0



    constraintHeight.isActive = true
  constraintWeight.isActive = true


}




func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat){

    constraintHeight.constant = constantHeight
    constraintWeight.constant  = constantWidth
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = true

}


func scrollViewWillBeginZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?) {
   scrollView.clipsToBounds = false
}


func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}
```

Comment: your solution kinda worked, but the image doesnt fit snugly within the width still. Moreover, hard coding 200 from topAnchor isn't a scalable solution. I will need this work for all devices.